# 'Http error 0' when loading dynamic form elements in drupal 6, when an upload field has a file selected

Tags: drupal, ahah

I have a custom form implemented in a custom module in drupal 6.
The form contains an upload field, a textfield and a select dropdown.
When the dropdown fires a change event, two textfields are loaded dynamically below the dropdown through drupal AHAH.
This is based largely on: http://drupal.org/node/331941
The form functions correctly.

However, if I happen to browse to a file from the upload field and then change the dropdown, I get the nasty 'http 0 error'. Note: I am not submitting the form. I am simply selecting the file to upload and then changing the dropdown to fire the change event.
This problem is very much like: http://drupal.org/node/399676
However the solution provided in the same thread: http://drupal.org/node/399676#comment-1438662 doesn't work for me.

I changed the drupal_json call to drupal_get_js call as mentioned in the solution comment above, but I simply get an error alert containing some JSON.

I believe the problem is to do with the headers set by drupal_json as seen in the definition here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_json/6

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark...do you have the Theme Developer module enabled? Last time I had this problem that module was responsible :/

Comment: I did have Theme Developer enabled. I disabled it and retried. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be such a pervasive problem, that I simply moved to drupal 7 - 
upgrading all my custom modules to 7.

I looked everywhere online and found many suggestions and none of them worked. 
If someone else ever comes across this problem, I highly suggest you go the same path and simply upgrade to d7. The d7 FAPI is so much more robust, especially where ajax based dynamic forms are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this at one point.  There are a bunch of threads around saying it has something to do with APC .. however for me what fixed it was changing the progress indicator on the file field from "bar with progress meter" to "Throbber"  under the file field settings

Comment: When you configure the field, it is a preference there if APC is available on your server.  If it is not, the field will not be shown

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf`.

Add this line at the end:

```
MaxRequestLen 536870912
```

for 512MB or 1073741824 for 1GB (the value is in bytes). If the parameter is already set, consider increasing until the error goes away.

Also, don't forget to make sure you have increased your `memory_limit` > `post_max_size` > `upload_max_filesize` limits in `php.ini` or `.htaccess` depending on where you're setting these.

Taken from [this Drupal posting](http://drupal.org/node/434394#comment-6229400).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue using this "hijacked ... code from the upload module (including comments)" by jleonard (at) drupal.org on April 4, 2009 at 9:24pm:

```
// send the updated file attachments form...  don't call drupal_json().
  // ahah.js uses an iframe and the header output by drupal_json() causes
  // problems in some browsers.
  print drupal_to_js ( array ( 'status' => TRUE, 'data' => $output ) );
  exit;
```

From (http://drupal.org/node/399676#comment-1438662)